# add href to div on selected area

Tags: jquery, html, css

Having div like ,

```
<div id="footer">

<div>
```

I have defined background image to this div from css.
It looks like ,

[image]

Want to add href to this image but at selected portion only ? Is it possible to do it ?

Selected Area is like ,

[image]

The mouse pointer should looks like normal on entire div except clickable area.

Comment: Try using map: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: You cannot add a map to a background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using CSS

CSS

```
#footer{
    background:#f00;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;

}
#footer a.link{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    float:right;
    margin:20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="#" class="link"></a>
<div>
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/QUXGe/)

Comment: Spend sometime while posting your solution

Comment: Whenever you are posting a link to JSFiddle must post some code. See a simple edit helped OP and you gained some reputation. Also remember SO doesn't promote Link only answers(they will be flagged and might be deleted). I am mentioning it so that you become a better contributor to SO

Answer (score 2):

You can add a child div into your footer and bind click event to it.

```
$('#childDiv').bind('click', function() {
window.open('/nextpage.html', '_self');
```

Apply css  to reposition child div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map and define more than one clickable area on a picture.

See this page. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: You may also use [http://www.image-maps.com](http://www.image-maps.com) to help you map the image.

Comment: You cannot add a map to a background image.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with HTML Image Mapping. here we go !

Set your coordination accordingly within the Div Position. so it can be done. and also you can place many Image Maps within one DIV

```
<img src="rainbow.gif" usemap = #example border=0> 
<map name=example>
<area shape=Rect Coords=0,0,29,29 Href="http://www.yahoo.com"> 
<area shape=Rect Coords=30,30,59,59 Href="http://www.hotbot.com"> 
</map>
```

Check this [tutotial](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks07.htm)